# different shell behaviors of unmatched glob in zsh and bash

Tags: shell, zsh, glob

When I use a miniconda environment, I want to use this command to install a python package.

```
pip install recommenders[examples]
```

In zsh, it returns a error.

```
zsh: no matches found: recommenders[example]
```

In bash, it is successful and installs the package.

Someone told me that zsh treats unmatched glob as an error, but bash treats it as a literal text.

How should I change `.zshrc` in order to make zsh behaves like bash at this point, aka treats unmatched glob in "[]" as a literal text?

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

(Besides, I am a beginner to zsh. I even don't know how to google it. What is the keyword of this problem? thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setopt NONOMATCH` to leave an unmatched glob as literal text.

Similarly, use `setopt NULL_GLOB` to treat an unmatched glob as if it hadn't been used at all.

Some examples:

```
% print recommenders[examples]
zsh: no matches found: recommenders[example]
% setopt NONOMATCH
% print recommenders[examples]
recommenders[examples]
% print recommenders[examples]

%
```

Both options are documented under `man zshoptions`. (Use `man zsh` to see what man pages are available, or `man zshall` to see all of them at once.)